# JavaScript - Find multiple objects by IDs existing in prefined list from an array of objects without using the for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JavaScript array of objects:

```
var my_array = [
  {
    "id" : 1,
    "aas_name" : "aaa"
  },
  {
    "id" : 2,
    "aas_name" : "bbb"
  },
  {
    "id" : 3,
    "aas_name" : "ccc"
  },
  ...
   ...
    ...
  ,
  {
    "id" : 10,
    "aas_name" : "jjj"
  }
]
```

I would like to find all objects in the `my_array`, each of which has the id value that exists in a pre-defined array [1, 3, 8] for instance without having to use the `for... loop` and ES6 arrow function style.

```
var result = [
  {
    "id" : 1,
    "aas_name" : "aaa"
  },
  {
    "id" : 3,
    "aas_name" : "ccc"
  },
  {
    "id" : 8,
    "aas_name" : "hhh"
  }
]
```

Comment: Use a `.filter`, `var result = my_array.filter(function(item) { return [1,3,8].indexOf(item.id) != -1 });`

Comment: @MaksymPetrenko this should be posted as answer instead as comment mate :)

Comment: @CodeManiac posted it, thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

Use a `.filter`:

The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.
[`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var my_array = [{"id": 1,"aas_name": "aaa"},{"id": 2,
"aas_name": "bbb"},{"id": 3,"aas_name": "ccc"},{"id": 8,"aas_name": "hhh"},{"id": 10,"aas_name": "jjj"}]

let result = my_array.filter(function(item) {
  return [1, 3, 8].indexOf(item.id) != -1;
});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: `my_array.filter(function(item) {
    retrun [1,3,8].includes(item.id)
})`
Would work as well :)

Comment: For bigger data it would be more efficient to create a hashtable first and instead of indexOf do lookups on it. Instead of O(n * m) we'd have O(2 * n) (or O(3 * n)). This works well though!